# Basic Poker Program - Printing Deck

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, poker

I'm working on a poker project that just deals the 5 top cards from a shuffled deck and lets the user to reject all, some, or none. I understand that there should be ideally 2-3 classes, one with the actual main and the other two being the card and deck. I have created the Deck class and a very basic Tester program that is just supposed to print the shuffled cards. However, when I print the deck, I get something along the lines of "Deck@###d##a". What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
// Constructing a deck from two arrays
String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
String[] rank = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
String[] deck = new String[suit.length * rank.length];

// Storing public variables
int suits = suit.length;
int ranks = rank.length;
int deckSize = deck.length;

public Deck()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < suits; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < ranks; j++)
        {
            deck[ranks*i + j] = rank[j] + " of " + suit[i];
        }
    }
}

// Fisher-Yates Shuffle 
public void shuffle()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < deckSize; i++) 
    {
        int x = rand.nextInt(deckSize);
        String temp = deck[x];
        deck[x] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = temp;
    }

}

}
```

And the tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DeckTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Deck deck = new Deck();

    System.out.println(deck);
}

}
```

Output: Deck@###d###a

Comment: You need to override the toString method in your Deck class. Also consider using an Enum instead of String arrays since you have a defined set of values.

Comment: Also, your shuffle is NOT a correct Fisher-Yates. If you copied that from another source, you may want to advise them of their error. The Wikipedia article is a good source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the default `toString() method from the Object class, and you're finding that it's not too helpful. You're also not creating a Card or a true Deck class and so you can't give any class a decent toString() method.

Solutions:

- Create a Card class.
- Give it a rank and a value field.
- Give it a `toString()` method.
- Create a Deck class
- Give it a collection of Cards.
- Give it a decent `toString()` method.

e.g.,

```
// for Deck
@Override 
public String toString() {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (Card card: cards) {
      sb.append(card.toString() + ", ");
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: For just printing out all of the cards of the deck alone, can I use Arrays.toString(deck)? I'm trying to just create the object Deck and print its contents (52 cards in order in one list). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Printing an object calls its `toString()` method. If your class or any of its ancestors do not override `toString()`, it calls the default, which is the `toString()` method of `Object`.

But the default `toString()` is not very clever - it just gives you the name and hash code of the deck.

So it is very recommended, for any class that you're going to print (and even for those you don't, but you may want to debug) to override the `toString()` method. In the overridden method, you should construct a string that represents the contents of your class. It could be as simple as calling `Arrays.toString()` in your case.

Also, note that you have defined a `shuffle()` method, but you are not actually calling it from anywhere, so once you do succeed in printing your deck, it will not be shuffled.

Comment: I used `public String toString() {
  return Arrays.toString(deck);
 }` but it prints it all in one line. How can I get it all in one list?

Comment: What do you mean "one list"?

Comment: Ace of Clubs (next line) 2 of Clubs (next line) 3 of Clubs

Comment: Each card printed on its own line (52 lines), essentially. Basically printing array contents in separate lines.

Comment: Then you have to do it similarly to what Hovercraft Full Of Eels has shown in his answer: use a StringBuilder, append the items to it, but instead of appending a comma, append `"\n"`.